# Can you reach back into the local machine and execute an application with parameters from your remote session?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, c#, rds

I am writing a program that is used as a RemoteApp from server to the client machine.

I know that using `System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession` I can determine if the current session is a local session or a remote session from RemoteApp execution.

Is there a way for me, if Terminal Server Session is true (when user is running the app remotely), to tell the local machine to execute an application, like MS Word? I'd like do it natively, without use of plug-ins or psexec if it can be helped.

Comment: http://www.tricerat.com/blog/166

Comment: @STTR Relevance?

Answer (score 1):

depands how remote the users are from the server but lets assume they are all in an office at the end of a network or VPN.

I'd create dotNet app that connects to a central SQL Server and scan every 250ms for a simple record with your PC name. The second field in the record is the program to run.

This means that a server based app can write to the DB every tie it wans to open a program locally. within 250ms the local app will find the record, launch the app and delete the record.

Answer (score 0):

you have 4 options with varying degrees of complexity, reliability, and deployment considerations.

1) PSEXEC. seriously, lots of people use psexec for this purpose, and works most of the time. by far the simplest solution. use -i so it can interact with the desktop.

2) WMI. you can write .net or VBScript code to execute the client app. its just as scripty as psexec, but is entirely native. I've had reliability problems with WMI before, but those were domain wide automated ops, and much of the issue appeared to be power management on idle workstations. 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31113/Create-a-Remote-Process-using-WMI-in-C

3) Windows task scheduler. from the server schedule a task to execute on the client in the users session. still scripty, with lots of moving parts. 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

4)create a windows network service for the local PC, and upon signal, launch the task under the users session. you may have to use the task scheduler to accomplish this. lots of work to dev and test, hard to deploy, lots of moving parts, and still scripty in places, but this would probably be microsofts answer, as it correctly implements their guidance for process elevation.

Comment: So with PSEXEC, I'd be remoting from the client machine to the client machine from the RemoteApp to execute an application?

Comment: yes. more or less. the actual execution of the RemoteApp is occurring on the server, which is why you can't just do a Process.Start(path); the winword process would start on the server. so its more precise to say that the client is connecting to the server to get the output of the remote app, and the server is connecting to the client to run the local one. PSexec would be placed on the server where the remoteapp can call it.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way I could use the Environment variables in C# to do it, since using PSEXEC would mean the client would need to authorize more stuff to be added to their server.

Comment: Its not about environment config per se, though I suspect path variables from the remoteApps environment would resolve to server-side paths. Besides even if you got the path on the client, if the remoteapp process executed it, it would still be running on the server, not the client. just drop psexec in the bin directory as a dependency, or look at the taskscheduler/wmi methods.